# What is a compatibility version of a map?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Some popular maps on CS:GO have compatibility versions. I am wondering why a map would need compatibility versions whatsoever? What does it mean to need a compatibility version, and what makes it any different from a normal map? I have a very bad computer but I can still run CS:GO on low settings at a reasonable framerate.  What would make a compatibility version any different? Would it run faster than the normal iteration of the map?

[image: Steam Workshop]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These *compatibility versions* are older versions of official matchmaking maps. They enable the correct playback of recorded match demos. Any changes on a map can make demos useless, as boxes or barrels are for example slightly moved.

Comment: So compatibility versions are not for playing but only exist for legacy demos, correct?

Comment: @memescientist No they should behave like any other map. This is just what they are used for.

Comment: @Jojo or OP, do you know if these maps are published by Valve officially? Or is someone posting them?

Comment: @Mo2 I can'T guarantee for all compatibility maps. But mostly they are provided by a Steam Account called *CS:GO Official*. That seems to be an official valve account. But there's no way to prove this:
https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198082857351/myworkshopfiles

Comment: @Daniel that's what I'm wondering. Is it an official Valve account. I can't seem to verify it.